# Create a collection resource with Sort and querydsl Predicate but no Pageable

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest, querydsl

I'm using Spring data Rest and looking for a way to create a Collection (or search) resource having Sort and Predicate (using querydsl) capabilities but no Pager without luck.

Until now, i only needed to disable pager but have Sort capabilities. It worked well using the following and calling `GET /userAccounts/search/noPager` :

```
public interface ReportRepository 
    extends JpaRepository<Report, Integer>{

    /**
     * Non paged data with Sort capabilities
     */
    @RestResource(path="noPager")
    List<Report> findAllBy(Sort sort);
```

Now i need to add Predicate capabilites. If i do the following:

```
public interface UserAccountRepository 
    extends JpaRepository<UserAccount, Integer>,
            QueryDslPredicateExecutor<UserAccount> {

    /**
     * Non paged data with Sort capabilities
     */
    @RestResource(path="noPager")
    List<UserAccount> findAllBy(Predicate predicate, Sort sort);
```

I get the following error when calling `GET /userAccounts/search/noPager`:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to detect parameter names
>   for query method
>   fr.texsys.datemplus.dm.domain.data.UserAccountRepository.findAllBy!
>   Use @Param or compile with -parameters on JDK 8.
>           at org.springframework.data.repository.support.ReflectionRepositoryInvoker.prepareParameters(ReflectionRepositoryInvoker.java:235)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
>           at org.springframework.data.repository.support.ReflectionRepositoryInvoker.invokeQueryMethod(ReflectionRepositoryInvoker.java:206)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar!/:na]

More strange, i tried to use QueryDSL with a CrudRepository, which has no pager capabilities. If i extend a CrudRepository with  `QueryDslPredicateExecutor<UserAccount>`, and call the collection resource `GET /userAccounts` the Pager is activated.

Without `QueryDslPredicateExecutor`:

```
public interface UserAccountRepository 
    extends CrudRepository<UserAccount, Integer> {
```

There is no pager:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "userAccounts" : [...]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:15571/userAccounts"
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:15571/profile/userAccounts"
    }
  }
}
```

But with `QueryDslPredicateExecutor`:

```
public interface UserAccountRepository 
    extends CrudRepository<UserAccount, Integer>,
            QueryDslPredicateExecutor<UserAccount> {
```

The pager is activated

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "userAccounts" : [ ... ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:15571/userAccounts"
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:15571/profile/userAccounts"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 3,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i managed do to what i want but it is really cumbersome and hope there is a lighter and more convenient way i've not discovered:

1: Create a custom `QuerydslRepositoryInvokerAdapter` and route the `invokeFindAll(Pageable pageable)` method to the `findAll(Sort sort)` of the `executor`:

```
public class CustomQuerydslRepositoryInvokerAdapter 
        extends QuerydslRepositoryInvokerAdapter {

    private final QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Object> executor;
    private final Predicate predicate;

    public CustomQuerydslRepositoryInvokerAdapter(
            RepositoryInvoker delegate, 
            QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Object> executor,
            Predicate predicate) {
        super(delegate, executor, predicate);

        Assert.notNull(delegate, "Delegate RepositoryInvoker must not be null!");
        Assert.notNull(executor, "QuerydslPredicateExecutor must not be null!");

        this.executor = executor;
        this.predicate = predicate;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<Object> invokeFindAll(Pageable pageable) {
        return executor.findAll(predicate, pageable.getSort());
    }

}
```

2: Create a custom `RootResourceInformationHandlerMethodArgumentResolver`:

```
public class CustomQuerydslAwareRootResourceInformationHandlerMethodArgumentResolver 
    extends RootResourceInformationHandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    private final Repositories repositories;
    private final QuerydslPredicateBuilder predicateBuilder;
    private final QuerydslBindingsFactory factory;

    public CustomQuerydslAwareRootResourceInformationHandlerMethodArgumentResolver(Repositories repositories,
            RepositoryInvokerFactory invokerFactory, ResourceMetadataHandlerMethodArgumentResolver resourceMetadataResolver,
            QuerydslPredicateBuilder predicateBuilder, QuerydslBindingsFactory factory) {

        super(repositories, invokerFactory, resourceMetadataResolver);

        this.repositories = repositories;
        this.predicateBuilder = predicateBuilder;
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    /* 
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RootResourceInformationHandlerMethodArgumentResolver#postProcess(org.springframework.data.repository.support.RepositoryInvoker, java.lang.Class, java.util.Map)
     */
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
    protected RepositoryInvoker postProcess(MethodParameter parameter, RepositoryInvoker invoker,
            Class<?> domainType, Map<String, String[]> parameters) {

        Object repository = repositories.getRepositoryFor(domainType);

        if (!CustomQueryDslPredicateExecutor.class.isInstance(repository)
                || !parameter.hasParameterAnnotation(QuerydslPredicate.class)) {
            return invoker;
        }

        ClassTypeInformation<?> type = ClassTypeInformation.from(domainType);

        QuerydslBindings bindings = factory.createBindingsFor(null, type);
        Predicate predicate = predicateBuilder.getPredicate(type, toMultiValueMap(parameters), bindings);

        return new CustomQuerydslRepositoryInvokerAdapter(invoker, (QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Object>) repository, predicate);
    }

    private static MultiValueMap<String, String> toMultiValueMap(Map<String, String[]> source) {

        MultiValueMap<String, String> result = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();

        for (String key : source.keySet()) {
            result.put(key, Arrays.asList(source.get(key)));
        }

        return result;
    }


}
```

3: Overwrite the RootResourceInformationHandlerMethodArgumentResolver Bean definition:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

    @Autowired ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public RootResourceInformationHandlerMethodArgumentResolver repoRequestArgumentResolver() {

        if (QueryDslUtils.QUERY_DSL_PRESENT) {

            QuerydslBindingsFactory factory = applicationContext.getBean(QuerydslBindingsFactory.class);
            QuerydslPredicateBuilder predicateBuilder = new QuerydslPredicateBuilder(defaultConversionService(),
                    factory.getEntityPathResolver());

            return new CustomQuerydslAwareRootResourceInformationHandlerMethodArgumentResolver(repositories(),
                    repositoryInvokerFactory(defaultConversionService()), resourceMetadataHandlerMethodArgumentResolver(),
                    predicateBuilder, factory);
        }

        return new RootResourceInformationHandlerMethodArgumentResolver(repositories(),
                repositoryInvokerFactory(defaultConversionService()), resourceMetadataHandlerMethodArgumentResolver());
    }

}
```

4: Create a custom `QueryDslPredicateExecutor`:

```
public interface CustomQueryDslPredicateExecutor<T> extends QueryDslPredicateExecutor<T> {

    Iterable<T> findAll(Predicate predicate, Sort sort);

}
```

5: Then apply it to the Repository

```
public interface UserAccountRepository 
    extends CrudRepository<UserAccount, Integer>,
            CustomQueryDslPredicateExecutor<UserAccount> {
    [...] 
}
```

Ouch! but it works...

Comment: Pageable takes in a sort parameter now so you can avoid this by simply adding the sort criteria to the Pageable object via PageRequest.of(page, limit, sort). Then do myRepository.findAll(predicate, PageRequest.of(page, limit, sort));  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52627784/spring-data-query-dsl-how-to-add-order-by)

Answer (score 0):

What about extending [JpaSpecificationExecutor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.html) so you can use a [Specification](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specification.html)?

Creating your own Specification implementation will allow you to create your search filter and sort it like you want (by accessing CriteriaQuery).

Hope it's help...

Comment: I Took a look at the Specifications API. It looked promising at first but this is not what i need because using spring data rest i have no control on which  'listAll' method will be called (it is indirectly called by spring data rest layer when an HTTP request is done in the form /api/{repository}). Maybe what i need is create my own <Something>Executor but i don't know how to do that!