# Spring data query dsl how to add order by?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, querydsl

I'm new to Querydsl, I'm working on Spring data and Querydsl to make a dynamic filter, I use the interface: **QueryDslPredicateExecutor** so I can filter data using different entity fields, now I want to add "order by" to my query based on a **BooleanExpression**.

This my code:

```
QPersonData _personInventory = QPersonData.personData;
BooleanBuilder query = new BooleanBuilder();

query.and(_personInventory.status.eq(status));
```

Then I called my respository interface using the query:

```
personInventoryRepository.findAll(query, pageable);
```

My question is how I can apply "order by" to my query object based on different fields on my entity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks all finally this solution work for me :

```
 QPersonData _personInventory = QPersonData.personData;
 BooleanBuilder query = new BooleanBuilder(); 

 query.and(_personInventory .status.eq(status));
 personInventoryRepository.findAll(query,0, Integer.MAX_VALUE,new QSort(_personInventory.field1.asc(),_personInventory.field2.asc()));
```

Answer (score 6):

You can add sort to your page information:

```
 Sort sort = new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.ASC,"filedname").nullsLast();
 PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(pageNumber, pageSize, sort);
 personInventoryRepository.findAll(query,pageRequest);
```

Answer (score 5):

Add a method in your repository interface

```
findByStatus(status)
```

Then use code block like below

```
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(offset, limit, Direction.DESC, "updatedAt");
repository.findByStatus(status, pageable);
```

if your using spring boot 2.0.0 => 
then use method

```
PageRequest.of(....)
```